# Mark Jenkins Pipeline as Promoted

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Last I knew, Jenkins Pipelines did not support promotions, so to work around this, I created a job called "job-name-promotion" which would gather artifacts from the job I wanted to promote, and then mark the corresponding build as "Keep Forever." Is there a way to mark the build that was kept forever as "promoted" somehow? Preferably using one of the Stars that typically denote promotions? Or even better, is there a way to add Promotion Process steps to pipelines now?

Answer (score 1):

Since it appears that pipelines still do not support promotions (as of 11/21/2017), I wrote a custom groovy script to iterate over all the jobs on the Jenkins server, locate the one we wish to promote and add a gold star to the corresponding build number:

```
import hudson.model.*
import jenkins.model.*
import org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.groovypostbuild.GroovyPostbuildAction

def log = manager.listener.logger
build = Thread.currentThread().executable
String jobName = build.project.getName()
// note: these two variables are defined as parameters of the current job
def number = manager.build.buildVariables.get("NUMBER") as int
def buildJobName = manager.build.buildVariables.get("BUILD_JOB_NAME")

Jenkins jenkins = Jenkins.getInstance()
List<Job> projects = jenkins.getAllItems(Job.class)

for (Job project : projects) {
    if (project.getName().equals("platform-lanai-pipeline")) {
        log.println("Found it!")
        Run usb = project.getBuildByNumber(number)
        usb.getActions().add(GroovyPostbuildAction.createBadge('star-gold.png', ''))
    }
}
```